# How do you separate a string and/or number into an array?

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

I'm working with the language Lua, and I have a long string of binary numbers, which I'd like to put into an array with each digit as its own element within the array.

Comment: what version of Lua are you working with?

Answer (score 3):

```
local str, out = "01101101010010010", {}
for i = 1, #str do
  out[#out+1] = string.sub(str,i,i)
end
```

Change line 3 to `out[#out+1] = tonumber(string.sub(str,i,i))` if you want the array to contain numbers rather than strings.